# Using Django Admin search engine in my own views

Tags: python, django, search-engine, admin, attributeerror

I am trying to use the same search engine as Django uses in the admin page to show results in my custom views.

I found [this website](http://contrib.exoweb.net/browser/exoblog/trunk/blog/utils.py) that recommends to use the following code:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
import operator

def django_admin_keyword_search(model, keywords, base_qs=None):
    """Search according to fields defined in Admin's search_fields"""
    if not keywords: 
        return []
    fields = model._meta.admin.search_fields

    qs = QuerySet(model)

    for keyword in keywords:
        or_queries = [Q(**{'%s__icontains' % field: keyword}) for field in fields]
        if base_qs is None:
            other_qs = QuerySet(model)
        else:
            other_qs = base_qs
        if qs._select_related:
            other_qs = other_qs.select_related()
        other_qs = other_qs.filter(reduce(operator.or_, or_queries))
        qs = qs & other_qs

    return qs

def do_keyword_search(model, query, base_qs=None):
    return django_admin_keyword_search(model, query.split(' '),
                                       base_qs=base_qs)
```

but i am not being able to run that without getting an **Attribute Error ('Options' object has no attribute 'admin')** at this piece of code: `fields = model._meta.admin.search_fields`

**EDIT:**
What am I doing wrong on using the admin default search engine?

Is that any other way to use the default admin search engine?

Comment: Note the date on that link: **7 years ago**. That's well before Django 1.0, and the admin was quite different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to build my own generical search that works like the admin search. The class is as follows:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
import operator

def django_admin_keyword_search(model, keywords, search_fields):
    """Search according to fields defined in Admin's search_fields"""
    all_queries = None

    for keyword in keywords.split(' '):  #breaks query_string into 'Foo' and 'Bar'
        keyword_query = None

        for field in search_fields:
            each_query = Q(**{field+'__icontains':keyword})

            if not keyword_query:
                keyword_query = each_query
            else:
                keyword_query = keyword_query | each_query

        if not all_queries:
            all_queries = keyword_query
        else:
            all_queries = all_queries & keyword_query

    result_set = model.objects.filter(all_queries).distinct()

    return result_set
```

Enjoy !!

Answer (score 0):

This already has a working answer by the questions author. However, if you want to use the same search as used by the admin directly in your view, you can do the following:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from my_app.admin import MyModelAdmin
from my_app.model import MyModel


def my_view(request):
    user_query = request.GET.get("q", "")  # or however you get the user's query
    model_admin = MyModelAdmin(MyModel, admin.site)
    queryset = MyModelAdmin.get_queryset(request)
    results, _ = model_admin.get_search_results(request, queryset, user_query)
```

`results` then is a queryset with `MyModel` objects. Note that we discard the second return value which is a boolean indicating whether there might be duplicates in the queryset.

The use of `get_queryset(request)` makes sure, that the user set on the request has the proper permissions to view the model instances. You could alternatively use `MyModel.objects` here if you are sure there are no permission issues.

Using this you can actually get rid of `request`, e.g. if you are not in a view context, as `ModelAdmin` (currently) does not actually use it. This might break in the future, but a minimal example for using the admin search is:

```py
model_admin = MyModelAdmin(MyModel, admin.site)
results, _ = model_admin.get_search_results(None, MyModel.objects, "some query")
```